# Angular build index file: where does the injected style come from?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular application which I have just finished migrating from v7 to v12. I use my own custom index file (perhaps this makes no difference), ie I have the following in my angular.json file...

```
"projects": {
"routes": {      
  "architect": {
    "build": {          
      "configurations": {            
        "production": {
          "index": "src/index.aspx",  // <---- my index file
```

When I build, and this file is copied, has Angular bundles injected etc, it also adds a long style

```
<style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--blue:#628aba;--indigo:#510fbd;--purple:#5a379b;--pink:#e83e8c;--red:#a11422;--orange:#ce640d;--yellow:#ffff85;--green:#178f33;--teal:#20c997;--cyan:#17a2b8;--white:#fff;--gray:#757575;--gray-dark:#3b3b3b;--primary:#628aba;--secondary:#b5b5b5;--success:#178f33;--info:#17a2b8;--warning:#ffff85;--danger:#a11422;--light:#fafafa;--dark:#3b3b3b;--breakpoint-xs:0;--breakpoint-sm:576px;--breakpoint-md:768px;--breakpoint-lg:992px;--breakpoint-xl:1200px;--font-family-sans-serif:Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica sans-serif;--font-family-monospace:Consolas,"Courier New",SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,"Liberation Mono",monospace;}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;}html{font-family:sans-serif;line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);}body{font-size:1rem;font-weight:400;line-height:1.5;color:#000;text-align:left;background-color:#fff;}@page {size:a3;}body{min-width:992px!important;}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.86e8f850c5457bf98a6f.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.86e8f850c5457bf98a6f.css"></noscript>
```

I am wondering where this comes from? Is this from the global `styles.scss`? I would not recognize as my `styles.scss` links to other styles not done by myself (eg Angular material)

My one issue is this, unknowingly to me, has included

```
body{min-width:992px!important;}
```

So I was trying to work out where this was coming from, as I don't want it. I have look through all our own shared etc styles, and can't find this anywhere. Also did a search through the materials `node_modules` folder, not finding it.

For now I am overriding it on the `body` element, but would  like to know where all these come from?

Comment: Have you tried a global search with min-width:992px? Or a global search for !important?
btw, from angular.json, check the path: `projects.project_name.architect.build.options.styles` This is an array of styles.

Comment: did you solved this issue, I got same issue after update angular version 12?

Comment: Not yet found where it is coming from (the only place I see 992px) is one of bootstraps breakpoint widths, but no idea what that get put into here. My workaround at the moment is I just have `<body style="min-width: 100px!important"` in my index file

Answer (score 6):

It comes from `inlineCritical` optimization option. See details here https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-optimization-options

Just set it to `false` in your `angular.json` file:

```json
"project": {
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": {
            "scripts": true,
            "styles": {
              "minify": true,
              "inlineCritical": false
            },
            "fonts": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you very much! I still couldn't find who adds that style definition though.

Comment: After some more searches through my project's CSS, I found that `bootstrap.css` has a `@media print` selector that defines `@page {  size: a3;  }  body {  min-width: 992px !important;  }`, which is exactly what the generated `index.html` contains. Why is that incorporated I still cannot figure out.

Comment: i ve the same exact issue , and i wonder the main reason

Comment: @ovidiu even with that build option , that still exist for me

Comment: @firasKoubaa: I don't know why you still see that. If I were you, I'd remove the offending content with a sed command, after the build finishes, in the shell script that I use to push the distribution files to the Web server.

Comment: it s not clean to delete it that way

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in version 12. After upgrading Angular to version 13, it seems it's been fixed.